# Speed up custom DATE_BETWEEN function

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime

Below function (+usage example) implements some business logic that I need to use in a rather complex select query, which is already pushing our database server towards it's limits. Below code (copy/paste ;-) takes us about 35ms to run (without the drop and create) with the 2-option CSV; I need to get this faster ...

**What it does**

Give me a later startDate before endDate from a CSV of options , or -when endDate is invalid- just after startDate.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS later_start_before_end_date;
delimiter $$
CREATE FUNCTION later_start_before_end_date(startDate DATETIME, endDate DATETIME, optionsCSV CHAR(255)) 
RETURNS DATETIME
-- COMMENT "Choose the latest alternative start-datetime from a comma-separated optionsCSV of UNIX timestamps that is inbetween startDate DATETIME and endDate DATE"
-- COMMENT "endDate value of NULL will be interpreted as INDEFINITE"
BEGIN
--  SET @optionsCSV = CONCAT(optionDate1, ',', optionDate2); -- e.g. "2002-10-10 02:01:00,2005-10-10 23:21:00"
    SET @isIndefiniteEnd = (ISNULL(endDate) OR endDate LIKE("0000-00-00%"));
    SET @returnValue = startDate;

    WHILE (NOT ISNULL(optionsCSV) AND (optionsCSV) != '') DO
        SET @strLen = LENGTH(optionsCSV);
        SET @altDate = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(optionsCSV, ',', 1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
        SET @isAfterNewStart = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @returnValue, @altDate) > 0);

        CASE (@isAfterNewStart) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 
            SET @isBeforeEnd = (NOT @isIndefiniteEnd /* timestampdiff cannot calculate null or zero date! */
                    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, endDate, @altDate) < 0);

            CASE (@isIndefiniteEnd OR @isBeforeEnd)
            WHEN 1 THEN 
                SET @returnValue = @altDate;
            ELSE BEGIN END;
            END CASE;

        ELSE BEGIN END;
        END CASE;

        SET @subStrLen = LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(optionsCSV, ',', 1));
        SET optionsCSV = MID(optionsCSV, @subStrLen+2, @strLen);

    END WHILE;

    RETURN @returnValue;

END; $$
delimiter ;

/* Use it ... */
SET @startDate = STR_TO_DATE('2002-10-10 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
SET @endDate  = STR_TO_DATE('2003-10-10', '%Y-%m-%d');
/* ... edge cases for the above start-end */
SET @optionsCSV = CONCAT(
--  TIMESTAMP('2002-10-10 00:00:00'),
--  ',', 
--  TIMESTAMP('2002-10-10 00:00:01'),
--  ',', 
    TIMESTAMP('2003-10-10 00:00:00'),
    ',', 
    TIMESTAMP('2003-10-09 23:59:59')
    );
/* ... or a single timestamp */
-- SET @optionsCSV = TIMESTAMP('2002-10-10 00:00:01');
SELECT later_start_before_end_date(@startDate, @endDate, @optionsCSV);
```

**Goals and considerations**

- I'm looking for an improvement that would run the code above in **less then 10 ms**.
- I'm working in a company-legacy MySQL database (5.1.73) that has grown over the years to use **various date-time types** across the tables I need to access (DATETIME, DATE and TIMESTAMP) ... type changes are unacceptable,
- I wanted the function to have only **one single options parameter** to have more flexibility in possible other use-cases.
- Multiple options in date-formats (startDate, endDate, option1 TIMESTAMP, option2 DATETIME, ...) might be acceptable, if it would **really significantly** increase performance.

Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: If you really need this to be fast, you are better off implementing it as a UDF (written in C or C++) rather than a stored function. Info on implementing a UDF: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: I've not yet explored the territory of UDF; I'm just using this in PHP-code and my other skills are more towards front-end ... I hadn't considered UDF yet, but do now. Thanks!